# The other part of a polygon shape is not showing at a specific zoom level,I am using geoserver

Tags: image, geoserver, sld-resolution

This is the polygon shape looks like when zoom level at 20m,
the shape is not completely displayed compare to zoom 10 m

[image]

This is the polygon shape looks like when zoom level at 10m

[image]

Comment: Looks like the client did not receive (or did not ask?) for the missing tile there. Use the developer tools to find which is the case, locate the request and see what happens on the GeoServer side when you do it alone... do you get an error in the logs, for example?

Comment: @AndreaAime no error found on geoserver logs